# How to go about implementing level selection map that is repeatable texture in Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Basically I have an image that represents a map where you go from one level to another. I was planning for this image to repeat it selfie while you go up thru the map to new levels( something like the map in candy crush). What is the best way to implement this behavior? I was tanking to move an image and repeat it from top of a screen when it reaches certain point at the bottom but I'm not sure if there is a better way.
And also the map will probably be an UI image.

Comment: A seamless tile texture would take the need away to move the background by yourself. But if you want to implement it as UI image, normally your UI is fixed and does not move with the background.

Comment: The way you propose sounds like it would work, @Ivan..How have you tried putting your idea into practice so far? Did you run into a specific problem that we can help you solve?

Comment: I was thinking of doing it in the UI because the texture will have points that represent level stage and when you click it it will take you to that stage. So it seams a lot easier to position buttons that way.

Comment: @DMGregory didn't really try it yet I want to get some guidelines so I can do it the right way.

Comment: "Doing it" IS the right way. My advice would be to *always* try your idea for a solution first. If it goes wrong in some way, if you get stuck, or if you dislike something about the outcome, *then* ask here. That will help you ask a focused question about the specific issue that you found through real experience, with code examples or screenshots, etc. And it saves you from wasting time waiting on strangers like us in cases where your first idea actually would have worked fine. 

Comment: Thank for the advice I will try my way and if I get stuck I hope the help will come :).